# Is there a super-meta place where we can have question and answers about online communities?

Tags: discussion, community

I am looking for a place where I can exchange questions and answers with other people interested about online communities (preferably professional ones).

I am looking for getting or sharing knowledge about how do they act, motivations, behaviours,.…

This is not limited to stack exchange platform.

Comment: This should be tagged [status-completed] — [Stack Overflow is getting a place of its own](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212631/195817) — Dec 19, 2013.

Answer (score 3):

There is an [Area51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5648/moderators?referrer=-P9h2WCtnjNN-CahX8P22A2) that might interest you:

> **Moderators**
>
> Proposed Q&A site for people who run forums, IRC channels, give talks, etc. This is for the squishier questions. Hard questions about moderation software should still be on Stack Overflow or Super User.

The proposal is still in definition, and it's not *exactly* what you are looking for, but if you have some interesting question about moderating online communities you can post them there and help the proposal grow into a full site.