# Why http://meta.stackexchange.com redirect to http://meta.stackoverflow.com?

Tags: support, stackexchange-2.0, stackexchange.com

I had a question about the similarity of question which is suitable for several site created on Area 51.

As they are no longer in beta since a long time, I was expecting to post them on the global meta site of stackexchange. I can understand the site don't exist, but why doing a redirect since it as absolutely nothing to do with [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Don't forget that there is a http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/ too.

Comment: @mmyers : This is because I was thinking this [question](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/47657/what-are-the-steps-to-securing-encryption-keys-databases-on-an-unsecured-daas-pr#47657 "What are the steps to securing encryption keys/databases on an unsecured DAAS provider?") would get more help on serverfault and that I am wondering if it is suitable for both sites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because currently, the meta site for all of Stack Exchange sites is meta.stackoverflow.com - for historical reasons.

However, there is [work in place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212631/stack-overflow-is-getting-a-place-of-its-own) to separate this site to two - one site for Stack Exchange and one specific for Stack Overflow.

These will be, meta.stackexchange.com and meta.stackoverflow.com, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Because we do not yet have a meta site for entire Stack Exchange. Thus, currently we are using Stack Overflow Meta as the main Meta.

Comment: I cannot get the `\`code\`` in your post to compile. Please help? ;-)

Comment: Too much used to coding that give priority to code-block over normal comments :P