# Should Area 51 questions go on the new meta.stackexchange or on discuss.area51?

Tags: discussion, area-51

According to the [post about the new Meta Stack Exechange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212631/stack-overflow-is-getting-a-place-of-its-own) posts on Area 51 should be given their own topic. However there already is an [Area 51 discussion](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com). Now I’m curious what that should be used for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Area51 discussion questions are *usually* about area51 site proposals.

For questions about area51 itself, use the `[area51-meta]` tag on the Area51 discussion site, though Meta Stack Exchange might work too.

Comment: However every proposal also has their own discussion set (often with just a few discussions) so why not use that for discussions about a specific proposal?

Comment: @Thijser That discussion set is on discuss.area51. A discuss.area51 post is put in the discussion set if it links to the proposal.

Comment: Area51 Discuss is *supposed* to be used as its own Meta site, but the staff always describe it as the place questions go to die, so they don't particularly care.

Comment: The problem with that is indeed that you are very likely to get drowned in other stuff related to specific topics so that doesn't really work.

Comment: The information in my post was flat out wrong. Even being around since it was created, I had no idea we even had an area51-meta tag on the discussion site. My fault, I updated the post.

Comment: @TimPost I don't know, a51 discussion is rarely directly visited, most people go to it from the individual a51 proposals. So these discussions usually tumbleweed and unless we can get the discuss site a community and more visibility, I think that we should have non-proposal-specific discussions ([area51-meta] discussions) on MSE

Comment: @Manishearth It's an internal thing, Area 51 is patrolled daily by Robert, who looks after those discussions and that tag - visibility isn't really a big issue. It's just yet another way that it's a little .. well .. different. I just found out about it myself 20 minutes ago.

Comment: @TimPost Hmm. That work, though the lack of a community still bothers me.

Answer (score 3):

For questions about Area 51 *itself* - how it works, features it should have, community governance on the main or discussion site, use [discuss.area51.stackexchange.com](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com) instead, and tag your question [area51-meta](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/area51-meta).

The guidance I had in that announcement post was incorrect. Treat Area51 just like any other site, don't worry too much where something gets posted and feel free to just post it on the child meta, which in this case, is the discuss site. If something needs to be migrated to MSE, we'll handle it.

I've updated the post to reflect this.