# Where should 'finding code' question go

Tags: discussion, migration

I wanted to ask about my codes, rather my app, doing a thing that is not in the code.
I mean, I want something to happen, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21300308/filter-database-not-to-display-same-data/21301477?noredirect=1#21300308) then I saw a snippet, added it to my code, then the thing that I want actually worked. Now, the catch is that, there had been no event handling it but then it just fired. That's what I want to ask, instead of finding an error, I want to `Find the code that is triggering an event in my app` (checking codes) for me to use it again ~ I will be posting all of them for other people to check. Because I can't see it.

I don't think this question should be asked here, so I want to know, what SE site this will be eligible to?

Comment: Finding code? To google.com maybe? Or if you want find something in your code, to your local debugger?

Comment: I got not errors. I just want to find the code that adds items in my comboBox..(because I want to use it again) But I can't see it. I don't know if this is a bug or something in my VS2010.

Comment: That would be a question about a programing IDE (the program you use for programming; VS2010). That is on topic on stackoverflow, but you'll probably want to carefully explain your problem when you post it.

Comment: I agree with "carefully" part by @GeorgeDuckett - it was easy to misunderstood what you really wanted. "saw a snippet, added it to my code" made it all look for me as internet search for snippets issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *general* question about **how to find what's causing unexpected behavior in your code** is probably fine on either [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) or, perhaps better yet, on [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  It's a pretty interesting question, actually — I started writing a very short answer as a comment above, before realizing that it wasn't turning out so very short after all, and that it really wasn't on topic for Meta.

What you really *shouldn't* do, on *any* Stack Exchange site (or pretty much any other site, either), is dump a large pile of code into your question and just say *"analyze this for me, please!"*  Nobody wants to do that, and even if they did, the resulting answer would be just about useless to anyone but you.

(Note that a few SE sites, like, notably, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), are by their very nature somewhat more tolerant of such things.  However, even Code Review is not a "debug my code for me" service — it's more about having people *critique* your code and suggest improvements to it.  You *can* post your code there, and you'll probably get useful feedback on it, but it may or may not be the kind of feedback you asked for.)

Comment: yeah, at first, I thought that my question would fit SO's criteria but if I put on a lot code, I will get a lot of down vote to, that's why I asked in here first since, this is about SO, am I right?

Comment: This is the right place for asking questions _about_ SO and other Stack Exchange sites, yes. ([SO is going to be getting a separate meta site of its own soon-ish](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212631/stack-overflow-is-getting-a-place-of-its-own), but for now it's still all mixed up here.)