# Is there a meta reverse engineering site?

Tags: support, per-site-meta

I wanted to post a question to "meta reverse engineering", but I can't find it. Does the meta page not exist during beta phase or will "meta stackoverflow" be the correct place to ask the question?

Comment: BTW: if you google for "meta reverse engineering stackoverflow", it will note find it within the first page of search results. If you change the search to "... stackexchange", it is shown.

Comment: Well... yes... The network is of Stack Exchange sites, of which, Stack Overflow is one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Beta sites have site-metas, too. For reverse engineering, it's at https://reverseengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/ (meta.site.stackexchange.com in general)

First, navigate to the site in question, then use the dropdown to navigate between meta and the main site:

[image: StackExchange > Reverse Engineering Meta]

Or navigate to the site in question and then use the help dropdown:

[image: help > Meta]

Comment: With your help I found it. I was actually on Stackoverflow when I was looking for "meta.reverseengineering", therefore any meta link I saw was not the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

**Every** Stack Exchange Q&A site has a meta site attached (with a `meta.<site>.stackexchange.com` domain).

These are created at the same time the site is created - as it enters the private beta.

So, for:

http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com

The meta is:

https://reverseengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/

As others have answered - these are directly accessible from the site-switcher dropdown and from the help drop down of each site.

---

As for where is the right place to ask the question?

If it is specific to the community (Reverse Engineering, in this case) and the site (design, norms etc...), then the site meta is the right place to ask.

If the question is general and is applicable to the network as a whole, the network meta is the place to ask. Currently, that is meta.stackoverflow.com, but it will change to (the currently non-existent) meta.stackexchange.com - [there are plans underway to give Stack Overflow its own dedicated meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212631/stack-overflow-is-getting-a-place-of-its-own), just like all other sites do (that it doesn't is an accident of history).

Comment: If the question is about the reputation of a "reverse engineering" user, you would consider that as a network bug, because users on all sites are treated the same way?

Comment: @ThomasW. - if it is a reputation bug, then it would probably apply to the whole network. The codebase of all the sites is the same.