# What is the current ETA of Meta Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, meta, mso-mse-split

In [Stack Overflow is getting a place of its own](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212631/152515), the estimated time of arrival was around the middle of January:

> I'm *extremely* pleased to announce that we've finally worked out the remaining details, and will be proceeding with the split in six to eight weeks. No, I'm not kidding, we're shooting for somewhere around the middle of January. Seriously, stop laughing, six to eight weeks is a *perfectly* reasonab .. I digress.

It's February now, though, so I'm wondering: what's the current estimated time of arrival for the new Meta Stack Overflow?

I am absolutely not planning to hassle the development team here. I'm quite content whenever Meta Stack Exchange arrives, and if they need more time, they should definitely take it, since this is something that should be done right. I'm still curious about *when* it might happen, though!

---

A day later: I've just learned that [6-8 weeks is a meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/152515) for when there *isn't* an ETA. Was there no ETA to begin with, and is there no specific ETA now? (Other than a perpetual ETA of 6-8 weeks)

Comment: We apologize for any inconvenience caused. Please allow for 6 to 8 weeks for your refund application to be processed. A $19.95 administration fee will be subtracted from your refund.

Comment: @AlienArrays indeed

Comment: Three more weeks and done

Comment: Is this when the New World Order comes to take our Meta rep? Time to barricade myself with my double barrel and a year's worth of canned food. FROM MY COLD DEAD HANDS

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy No inconvenience, I'm just trying to find out when this _is_ happening, since it involves a read-only freeze and some significant changes. (I'm trying to _avoid_ getting defensive responses like this is some inconvenience to me!)

Comment: @Alien it does. But you'll have to prove you're not one of *them*. It's a very painful process. But you'll get to survive the Apocalypse, in cheerful company, so there's that.

Comment: @Pëkka Does your tinfoil hat interfere with the wifi?

Comment: @slugster no, it amplifies the signal.

Comment: 6-8 weeks, it's always 6-8 weeks. Yep.

Comment: [It actually was 6-8 weeks this time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212631/stack-overflow-is-getting-a-place-of-its-own#comment688430_212631)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

***Update - March 2<sup>nd</sup> 2014***

*Work on the back end of this is well underway, there's a lot of code specific checks to see if Meta SO is actually Meta SO, and some other stuff that's currently being addressed. I will put out a meta post when we near the ~1 week to blast off milestone to let folks know. I don't think it'll be much longer.*

---

It *really was* six to eight weeks when I posted it, according to our schedule.

Work has started on it, the community team side has prepared new copy, figured out how the help center and /about is going to work, identified a bunch of unresolved Stack Overflow specific things that should migrate back to MSO once both sites go live and other stuff. We're the ones pushing the project.

What we're waiting for right now is the developers to finish up some work overhauling our login system and some things associated with it. Once that's done, they're going to start by letting us know when we should be telling everyone to look out for maintenance mode.

It's going to happen. Every time I see a perfectly valid support question down voted here by people that *barely use Stack Overflow itself*, I want to scream. It's still a major priority, and it has been progressing - just not visibly.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know!

Comment: So, basically what you're saying is that it's going to be *another* six to eight weeks.  Literally.

Comment: More like 2 to 4, if all goes as expected.

Comment: *if all goes as expected* - I never experienced that in Software Development.

Comment: *I don't think it'll be much longer.* I dont believe anybody thinks that :P

Answer (score 9):

In [a comment on January 22](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212631/stack-overflow-is-getting-a-place-of-its-own#comment703507_212631) Tim Post said:

> We just met again about it today, due to a bit of backlog with the SSL stuff, it's probably going to be around the first week of Feb. I'll update the post again as soon as I have a firmer time frame. However yes, this is going forward and soon - the community team end of it is moving, we just have to let the devs clear some room off their plates before we go full throttle.

As far as I can see that's the latest official update.

Comment: Thanks; it's good to know this is actually happening soon and the ETA was not just a joke.

Comment: Honest, it wasn't a joke, it really _was_ six to eight weeks away when I posted that. I knew that was going to come back to haunt me, I just knew it :)