# What does Meta really mean?

Tags: discussion, meta

This website is Meta Stack Overflow, but I thought it's better to know if 
meta really means meta literally!

Just to give more knowledge about this website.

Is it related to only Stack Overflow? Or is it general questions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta

Comment: also http://english.stackexchange.com/q/48576/3946 which covers what the word "meta" literally means, and even explains the meta stackechange sites as well.

Comment: i know i asked what it means literatur

Comment: ['nuff said](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/07/meta-is-murder.html)

Comment: Literally? See [in a dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/meta). (last part of course, not ancient Rome or Chemistry)

Comment: If I understand correctly it [means murder](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/07/meta-is-murder.html)

Answer (score 5):

It's for questions about Stack Overflow, and Stack Exchange in general.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta

It is definitely **not** for general questions about anything. That would be [Quora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quora).

Also see (compiled from comments):

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta
- [When your 10-year old boy says “It’s meta,” what does it mean? In what situation and of what sort of object they use this phrase?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/48576/3946)
- [What does “It’s sorta meta,” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48174/what-does-its-sorta-meta-mean)

In the pipeline is separating "meta" about Stack Overflow and "meta" about Stack Exchange into separate sites: [Stack Overflow is getting a place of its own](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212631/183887)

Comment: [Stack Overflow is getting a place of its own](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212631/stack-overflow-is-getting-a-place-of-its-own)