# Will the future mSO share reputation similar to other metas?

Tags: support, reputation, meta, mso-mse-split

When the split occurs, will reputation be shared between meta and main Stack Overflow similar to the other meta implementations?

Specifically, if someone gains reputation on the future Stack Overflow meta, will that reputation change also be reflected in Stack Overflow main?

Or, will the reputation for Stack Overflow main and meta remain separate in the same fashion as its current state (albeit perhaps modified by the migration for the meta rep)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [The future of meta.stackoverflow and meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange):

> a proper per-site meta for Stack Overflow with integrated rep

From [Stack Overflow is getting a place of its own](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212631/stack-overflow-is-getting-a-place-of-its-own):

> In short, Stack Overflow and its new child meta site will be like every other site in the network;

From [a comment by Tim Post♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212631/stack-overflow-is-getting-a-place-of-its-own#comment684467_212631):

> Your rep on SO will be your rep on MSO. Your rep on MSE will be the rep you've earned here to date, and independent of all other sites. SO/MSO will work just like every other site / child meta that we have.