# Why is Meta SO the only meta site to appear in my list of accounts?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, meta

In my Stack Exchange network profile I can view a list of accounts on sites where I'm participating. But among these sites there is only one meta — Meta Stack Overflow. I am participating on other meta sites as well. Why are they not in this list? Or why does Meta SO appear in there?

[image]

Comment: but heavily related [Stack Overflow is getting a place of its own](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212631/stack-overflow-is-getting-a-place-of-its-own)

Comment: This is the "capital meta", the meta for all the other metas and is for site wide issues (as well as being the regular meta for stack overflow)

Comment: "capital meta" -- Shades of "The Hunger Games".

Comment: The fast history lesson that isn't quite covered in the duplicates is - Meta.Stack Overflow was **the** meta.  Then per-site meta's were launched to handle site specific issues that were not well suited for the whole universe and it has its own rep system whereas the other meta sites don't.  And Meta Stack Overflow does joint duty as the Meta site for Stack Overflow and the Meta site for the entire Stack Exchange universe.  But that will change soon (very soon) as per my related question..