# Issue with magic site links in comments on migrated posts

Tags: bug, comments, migration, magic-links

When a post is migrated, its comments are persisted to the target site. The "magic" comments, such as `[so]`, `[meta]` are supposed to be migrated as well. However, there seems to be a problem when migrating from Stack Overflow to Meta Stack Overflow.

> [image: After migration]

[This comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221381/why-is-it-so-difficult-to-get-a-straight-answer#comment718887_221381) was migrated along with [its question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221381/why-is-it-so-difficult-to-get-a-straight-answer) from Stack Overflow to Meta. As you can see, the magic comments to `[meta]` are no longer parsed as links.

> [Original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21811846/why-is-it-so-difficult-to-get-a-straight-answer-in-these-forums?noredirect=1):
>
> [image: Before migration]

Is this expected behavior? Will this no longer be relevant once Stack Overflow gets [its very own meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212631/stack-overflow-is-getting-a-place-of-its-own)?

**Update:**

Even after the separation of MSO and MSE, the issue is still there:

> [Post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276091/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it#comment113954_276091):
>
> [image: after MSO is a child meta]

Comment: Problem is that meta got no meta. :(

Comment: By the way, worth posting link to [original question on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21811846/why-is-it-so-difficult-to-get-a-straight-answer-in-these-forums?noredirect=1) where we can see the magic link parsed correctly. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard - thanks! Good point - I'll add it.

Comment: @AaronBrager Thanks for killing that last greengrocer's apostrophe (how did I miss it...?).

Comment: @michaelb958 No problem.  I think I like your edit comment more than mine.

Comment: @AaronBrager One of the perks of 2k: filling that box with how you *really* feel.