# Broken link in the Community Bulletin on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed

There currently appears to be a bug regarding the Community Bulletin on Stack Overflow. I have a feeling there *may* be a correlation between this and the fact that Stack Overflow is [getting its own meta.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212631/stack-overflow-is-getting-a-place-of-its-own)

> [image]

The anchor element also isn't clickable as there isn't an `href` attribute present.

[image]

Comment: I saw this as well; we can only hope that The Time Has Come.

Comment: `target=_blank` is not a problem, the missing `href` is :-)

Comment: Maybe that's pre-April-Fools'-Day joke? ...

Comment: I was going to post this issue when I saw this post...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for reporting - this is now fixed and will be out in the next build (rev 2014.2.20.1382, Meta rev 2014.2.20.1967).

Comment: So this isn't a sign of a coming mSE?

Comment: @Undo - funny you should say that. The bug came in from some work in that direction...