# Should the "Greatest Hits" page be given more prominence?

Tags: discussion, greatest-hits

I am very active on multiple Stack Exchange sites. Yesterday, I happened to chance across [a post on a per-site meta remarking that there is a Greatest Hits page](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/263/113). That post is *nearly eight years old*. How had I not heard of a fascinating feature which has been around for that long? Why does it not appear anywhere I can find in the UI?

Comment: [What should we do about Greatest Hits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243010/295232)

Comment: This doesn't seem sooo much different from checking the "Question" page and sorting by votes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Votes - Can you elaborate what the main difference is? (Roughly: What exactly makes a question a "great hit", technically?)

Comment: @Marco - It looks like the Greatest Hits page gets populated not just by upvotes, but also by question views. On some Exchanges, the two sets of questions might be very different.

Comment: @Marco13 **How are they calculated?** "The current algorithm divides the number of page views with the total amount of question and answer feedback received (adding a bonus for high view counts), excluding questions with less views than the median:- 123."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the limited info I have...

#### What this tool is

This tool may be interesting for active users of a website trying to improve the results that people see in Google. It heavily focuses on views, which most of the time come from search engines. Stack Overflow engine doesn't provide any other way to sort by views (other than SEDE), which is probably a good thing as it's known to cause issues (sorting by votes isn't much better, but at least it's hidden behind a menu now).

Why are views important? These are basically the results that people see in Google most often. If a question has a good score then it's good. If it doesn't then Google has mislead users to QA which doesn't answer their question. What's worse is that we don't know what users were actually searching for. We may guess, but we'll never know for sure, so we can't do much to improve a question — make its title more precise maybe, but not much more.

So while the tool can be helpful, it's hard to use it efficiently.

#### What this tool isn't

This tool isn't a good way to learn about most interesting questions on a website. Just sorting by votes would probably show more interesting results.

When I register on a QA site, I often sort questions by votes and explore for some time. This gives me a good idea what users of the site are interested in, what and how they discuss.

Sorting by views would give me a skewed idea — instead of showing what other active users are interested in, it'll show me what people from Google stumble upon most often.

#### Conclusion

While the tool may have practical uses, I don't think a link to it should be displayed in some prominent way. This is a tool for active users looking to improve Google results of their site, not some general exploration tool.