# Why was this (4227405) suggested edit rejected?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

Just wondering what it is about my [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4227405) caused it to be rejected?

Mainly for the future so I can learn how best to do edits.

Comment: @hims056 I didn't add [tag:stackoverflow], I kind of assumed questions on meta are for stackoverflow specifically or is that not the case?

Comment: At present, Meta Stack Overflow is also Meta Stack Exchange. But it is getting [a new place of its own](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212631/187824).

Comment: @hims056 Thanks for clarifying I didn't realise will tag site specific in future.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Qantas 94 Heavy choose to improve on your edit, and unchecked the 'this suggestion was helpful' checkbox when he submitted the new edit.

He used indentation instead of backticks to mark the expression, as that applies code highlighting too; so instead of:

```
`(^07[1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9][0-9]{7,8}$)`
```

he used:

```
    (^07[1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9][0-9]{7,8}$)
```

You can see the exact edit he made in the [revisions of the original post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22170589/revisions).

Personally, I might still have left the 'helpful' checkbox applied, but as you came here and asked about the rejection, I guess he achieved the goal of showing that there was a better option to formatting that line. :-)

Comment: Personally, I would still say the edit was helpful

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense. It was purely [tag:regex] so I didn't think it needed a full line code block I was just trying to emphasize the expression so thought using `inline` was best. It would have been nice to get some recognition rather than disappearing into a blackhole and having my edit comment hijacked.

Comment: That was a later edit.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian Yeah, he did but I fail to see how that justifies hijacking an edit. Flag it as helpful and add your own.

Answer (score 8):

I'm the one that rejected your edit. Admittedly I'm quite a strict reviewer and this one was close to being helpful for my own standards.

As [Martijn Pieters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140890/martijn-pieters) [mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224080/why-was-this-4227405-suggested-edit-rejected/224082#224082), if the code is not within a sentence, code blocks should be used.

Compare:

`dynamic model = GetExpandoObject(); //model type of ExpandoObject`

with

```
dynamic model = GetExpandoObject(); //model type of ExpandoObject
```

Without taking that into account, you only really added inline code spans to the `#` characters, which by itself would be considered "too minor".

Now I come to think of it, there isn't *that* much that could have been obviously improved on in this particular post -- I'd probably give you the benefit of the doubt for edits like these in the future, but note that if there's still other things that's glaringly obvious, I might still reject your edit.

In any case, thanks for asking about it on Meta -- I certainly didn't mean to be obnoxiously picky.

Comment: I'm not sure what I consider "too minor" when it comes to improving the formatting of question / answers but in the case I a regex expression I thought the inline block suited it better as it wasn't what I would call a code block, it's just an expression. The inline was purely to highlight it. Thanks for the explanation though, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian: sorry, forgot about the differences between American and British English, reverted.