# Why do some Meta SE sites have their own reputation count while the other don't?

Tags: support, meta-reputation

I noticed that some SE sites have their own reputation count ([Meta StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/256936/nickolai-leschov)) while the other don't ([Meta ServerFault](http://meta.serverfault.com/users/213756/nickolai-leschov))? What is the principle here?

Comment: Meta Stack Overflow is special and a historical "accident" - it serves as Meta for the whole network too, but that dual role is being split and SO will be getting a proper per site meta soon too.

Comment: ok, since this is a duplicate, am I supposed to promptly delete my question? But @Josh Mein already put an effort to provide a good answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Meta Stack Overflow is the only meta site with its own reputation. This is because it is not only the meta site for Stack Overflow, but it is also the Meta for all of the StackExchange network. This is reported to change soon though.

You can follow [Stack Overflow is getting a place of its own](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212631/stack-overflow-is-getting-a-place-of-its-own) to see the progress of Meta SO becoming the same as all other meta sites and the creation of Meta SE.

Comment: Wait. So this means once the change goes through, if you post a question on meta.SO for a feature request, and people don't like your request, you lose actual, important SO rep? (This seems sort of off, since it's been mentioned all over the place on meta that downvoting works totally differently on meta sites.) (Though I suppose feature requests would more frequently go on the whole-stack meta, but still. Suppose it was a just-SO request.)

Comment: @neminem - no. Just as up-votes on a per site meta don't confer rep, down-votes won't take it away.

Comment: @neminem no, the other way around. Voting on meta doesn't affect your score.

Comment: Ah. That makes way more sense. So there just isn't any concept of rep at all on meta sites anymore. (That also seems a little weird, that you could post stupid crap on meta and nothing would happen unless it was so stupid you got banned for it, but not as weird as how I was imagining.)

Comment: @neminem, you would post feature requests on meta.stackexchange, not meta.stackoverflow. and meta.stackexchange will have its own reputation (copied over from here during the split)