# Where are the moderators?

Tags: feature-request, bug, user-list

*(Feels strange that this does not seem to have been brought up before, I have searched for a duplicate but could not find any)*

It's nice that MSO/MSE got split up finally. However, I do feel that it's a bit awkward that https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators is completely empty.

I assume this is because MSE doesn't have elected moderators (whether it should have elections or not is a completely different topic).

It would be helpful if https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators showed... some moderators.

Comment: Maybe someone should re-record [this song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MuhaOg4xSaA&feature=kp) to be "where have all the moderators gone"!

Comment: @NickStauner Thanks! I thought it was strange that no one else had seemed to notice it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the original [MSO/MSE split](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212631/175498) question, the moderators on Meta will consist of solely community employees. It looks like Stack Exchange community employees don't show up in any moderator list (though they may have moderator powers).

As an example, [Freelancing.SE](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) has three appointed moderators, but I've seen Oded close questions on his own.

Comment: Then the Meta StackExchange site would be a perfect place to show these community employees!

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg - Actually, this can be found [here](http://stackexchange.com/about/team)