# Why aren't there moderator elections on Meta Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, meta, moderators, election

Why aren't there moderator elections here on Meta Stack Exchange?

It seems to be moderated only by employees. I know that there aren't elections because [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/election) it shows no election history.

Is there a reason for this? Should there be elections here?

Comment: There hasn't been a need for mods here since there's so many employees looking after it already.

Comment: Why do you think there *should* be elections here?

Comment: Maybe back when spam was a problem, it would've benefited from community mods. Speaking of which... Whatever happened to all the spam? There was so much of it that I could almost brag about my flag count.

Comment: @Mysticial - Oded happened to all the spam ;)

Comment: Related: [Meta's moderators are very shy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230077/metas-moderators-are-very-shy)

Comment: @ChrisF Oooh? What did he do? Super-awesome AI algorithm?

Comment: @Mysticial, I don't think so, he's just so damn quick ;)

Comment: There is still quite some spam but you generally don't see them. Often a few flags are enough already for mostly Oded to step in and burn them.

Comment: I just happen to have the homepage open... all the time ;)

Comment: Just having the homepage open doesn't help Oded, you have to stare at it the entire time to be as fast as you are.

Comment: @PatrickHofman - believe me, I miss a fair few. I just clean up after those.

Comment: Related: [Where are the moderators?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230243/where-are-the-moderators), [Why do no moderators appear under the moderators tab on Meta Stack Exchange?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259429/why-do-no-moderators-appear-under-the-moderators-tab-on-meta-stack-exchange)

Comment: I also suspect that since the only mods here are employees, private rooms in chat.SE can be used openly for internal communication without anyone from outside (even if it's a community moderator) from listening in.

Comment: @Mysticial Nah, there's other protections in place for that. Internal chat rooms used to live at chat.meta.stackoverflow.com long before the network meta was split off into its own site.

Comment: This Q is asking for the reason behind the lack of moderators here, whereas the other is asking how to view Meta's moderators. VTR.

Comment: @Random what exactly are you trying to learn further? Correct answer has been given, I don't think more attention to the question can bring a better answer.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard More attention doesn't necessarily mean that I need a better answer. I feel that many people haven't voted on this question and I feel that this question is an important question. I was honestly surprised when this question was mistakenly closed as duplicate.

Comment: @RandomPerson We care about knowing whatever issue it is that you feel deserves our attention, but you're not effectively communicating what that issue is when the bounty is posted, why we should care further, or what you feel should be done about it. Without that communication, when the situation repeats, people will progressively become much more likely to just ignore your bounties completely.

Comment: @Makyen Regarding https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1275691: Let's not accuse fellow users of wasting other people's time. By that logic, anything could be a considered as a waste of time in MSE. The purpose of the bounty is to make more people aware about this post. That's it.

Comment: @Makyen Regarding https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1275693: I am not forcing fellow users to look at the posts where I added bounties. It's their choice to open that post and spend/"waste" their time. If you feel I'm abusing the bounty system, feel free to report it to the appropriate authority.

Comment: @RandomPerson You're correct. It would have been better if I had said something which made it more clear that I was talking about the feelings which I was having, rather than, potentially, implying that you might be intentionally causing them. Perhaps something like: "I feel your bounty here wasted my time. I'm frustrated, because I want to care about whatever issue it was that you were trying to address with the bounty, but there's nothing here that appears to deserve further attention. When posting a bounty, please provide more communication as to the issue which you're trying to address."

Comment: @Makyen Fair enough. I'll try to improve the way I do things w.r.t. starting bounties.

Comment: @Makyen (& Random Person), regarding [your comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281569/why-arent-there-moderator-elections-on-meta-stack-exchange#comment1275693_281569) - For > 10 years the use of a message has been optional, source: [staff comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130837/bounty-messages-bump-and-bump-are-dropped-silently#comment359758_130837) and [tag excerpt](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/bounty-remarks/info). It is considered a legitimate bump: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111714/282094 and the FAQ https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48578/282094

Answer (score 10):

There haven't been any elections because SE initially saw no need for there to be community moderators. We do now and they were appointed from the existing moderator pool (as I suggested in the last paragraph).

The real problem with having elections here is that there really isn't a community in the same way as on other sites to draw the potential candidates from. You want people who know the system and how SE works both at the individual site level *and* the network level.

The people best placed to do that are employees or moderators from other sites.

Back when this site was Meta Stack Overflow the moderators were appointed and were the "trilogy" moderators (Stack Overflow, Server Fault and Super User). That worked, but there were rather too many for the work that was required.

This is only my personal view but if there were to be community moderators here then the candidates would have to be drawn from the existing moderator pool. Whether they'd be appointed (if they wanted the job) or have to nominate themselves in an election is immaterial.

Comment: Are you soliciting for a new moderator job? ;)

Comment: @PatrickHofman - who me? What ever gives you that idea?

Comment: "The people best placed to do that are ... moderators from other sites." I would support you though.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure MSE has any special problems finding mod candidates. Enormous topic expertise isn't *really* essential for being a mod, and in any case it's not like we don't have high-rep users here, only some of which are mods anywhere on the network. Plus, mods not infrequently end up taking similar duties on multiple sites as it is.

Comment: That said, I do agree that there really isn't any particular reason to bother with elections here.

Comment: **ChrisF 2016**

Comment: And here I thought I was part of a community. I see how it is.

Comment: @Bart - Perhaps I was a little harsh there ;)

Comment: Haha, I was just kidding :D

Answer (score 6):

Well, at the time of posting of the question, there was no community moderation here. The site was moderated mostly by [the Community Team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99338).

> It seems to be moderated only by employees.

Is no longer true.

We have [appointed moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318630/please-join-us-in-welcoming-our-new-meta-stack-exchange-moderators) - though as anyone following the network is aware, the line up has changed a little with Monica's removal, and [us getting Glorfindel to top up the team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/366532).

> - There are no real growth initiatives that other sites might take on, or liaison roles between moderators and Stack Exchange like we'd see on other sites. However, we need people *with demonstrated experience* in navigating treacherous interpersonal dynamics and that's something that we're just going to have to select for based on observation. <sup>([Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318630))</sup>

I think this is *partially* true. Meta's *political*. While I'd not say it's a 'first amongst equals' amongst mods, it's a role that needs us to work with other mods, staff (occasionally when folks higher up do things that cause trouble) and the community in general. We don't always get advanced warning of changes (good or bad), so you're entirely likely to wake up to something new and exciting or new and terrible on your site.

The moderation program for meta was also meant as an experiment, one that's occasionally being tested and I'd argue in many ways still ongoing. It has been tested in quite a few ways, we have a few wins and a few failures, but for the most part, the core of the moderator team is the early appointees.

There's probably valid arguments for elected moderators - that 'appointed moderators' may lack independence - and ones against it, that practically there's a small number of regulars and 'meta enthusiasts' and we deal with issues across the network, for example. We might not be as big as MSO, but we're a resource for the wider network, not just 'us'.

Practically - it's a system that's mostly workable, and we don't have a huge amount of turnover since the original appointment of moderators. I have a certain bias towards saying we're essentially independent from the company's influence (though some may disagree). We have a moderator team that can handle the needs of this community - admittedly most work here is curation and cleanup. There's a fairly limited pool of folks interested in the role - there's a preference for folks who have moderation experience elsewhere *and* meta experience as well. *If* we need a top up, it might be worth opening up a conversation over how we handle it (full elections? Contacting folks to stand for an election? Having current mods suggest new mods?) and so on.

In short, we haven't had a moderator election since we've never really needed one, and while I certainly feel we need to consider our options as time goes on, things mostly work as they are.

Answer (score -2):

The trivial answer is that there hasn't been any need for elections yet, as the current mods are doing just fine. (This is the same proximate cause for a lack of active elections on any site at any time.)

The deeper answer is that not only is it conceptually elegant to have the dedicated whole-network meta site moderated solely by SE employees, it's also practical. On most sites, the elected (or appointed) mods do almost all of the moderation that the users can't (or won't). And, with the possible exception of SO and SU (which are a bit unwieldy to get a good grasp of), there really aren't any sites that *all* SE employees can contribute to. Here, neither of those is an issue, so, as a group, they get a peerless view of the entire workings of a healthy but medium-sized site from top to bottom.

And, of course, having no elections at the central site gives a healthy balance to the sometimes excessive focus on democracy elsewhere.

So not only do we not need elections here, I don't want them.