# Please welcome Glorfindel to the MSE moderation team

Tags: discussion, meta, moderation

After discussing it with the Meta Stack Exchange Mods, we're glad to welcome [Glorfindel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/glorfindel) to the MSE moderation team and we are excited that he's accepted the diamond here. As with the existing mods, he's been a moderator on the network for quite some time and seems like a natural addition to the team - indeed, some may assume he was one of them already.

In [November of 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318630/please-join-us-in-welcoming-our-new-meta-stack-exchange-moderators), we appointed the first set of moderators here on MSE. Up until that point, the staff moderated this site - at least since it split off from MSO. To be honest, I don't have much more to add to what Tim said there about moderation here, so feel free to refer to it if you're looking to understand why we have mods here, why they're appointed and that sort of thing.

It's been really great to have a team here handling flags and able to help clear up content that doesn't need to stick around and bringing things to our attention that they feel we should be aware of. While there's not currently a huge amount of things that need moderation here on MSE, the needs tend to ebb and flow over time.

For this round, we both considered people who the CMs thought might be good additions, as well as asking existing network mods to reach out by email if they were interested in the position. We talked with the existing team about all of the candidates before making the decision to add Glorfindel to the team. We were excited by all of the candidates and would have gladly seated all of them except for a dearth of work needed. We appreciate their willingness to serve!

Thanks so much to the existing mods. You've had a hard two and a half years moderating this site and you've done an admirable job of it. You've acted thoughtfully and deliberately and, while I know it's been difficult, we appreciate your efforts.

Comment: Congratulations Glorfindel. Dutchies rule!

Comment: Congratulations Glorfindel. :)

Comment: Congrats on your *6th* diamond, Glorfindel! :)

Comment: Congratulations Glorfindel! 

Comment: Awesome! Congrats!

Comment: I thought that Old Glori was too smart to take a mod post:)

Comment: "Glorfindel" and "rene" were appointed as moderator on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/users?tab=moderators) on June 02, there is no announcement about that. Since MSE is the Stack Apps meta site.

Comment: @Arulkumar some things are better kept  a bit blurry ...

Comment: @Arulkumar Stack Apps is its own meta site.

Comment: @animuson Thanks for the info, now I got it. Also, I found the Stack Apps [meta tag](https://stackapps.com/tags/meta/info)

Comment: @Arulkumar: Looks like it was sort of "announced" by another user in a [recent answer](https://stackapps.com/a/8952/80368) to this Q&A on Stack Apps: [Does this site need more moderators?](https://stackapps.com/q/8572/80368)

Comment: Two questions: (1) Why don't you do an election instead of appointing people? (2) If there's a "dearth of work needed", why did you add another moderator?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

**Thanks a lot!** I'd like say this to the community, the existing moderator team and staff alike.

First of all, for making Meta Stack Exchange a great place again. We all know what happened in the past, but right now it really feels to me like the old days (well, not too old, I've been a member for only 6-8 years) with lots of constructive discussions about the network and the system powering it. That would not have been possible without all your efforts. I've seen great contributions by veteran and relatively new users alike; please keep up the good work!

Second, for the trust you put in me; whether it has been by upvoting my answers or siding with me when it comes to moderation-actions-by-regular-users, and even by actively challenging my choices / pointing out my mistakes and hoping I'll do better in the future. And of course for entrusting me now with this position; it is both an honour and a privilege to serve you all.

Third, for all the kind words here and in various chatrooms and emails. I read them all but I hope you don't mind I'm not responding to each of you individually, at least not right now. You'll read my opinions about Dutch specialties and traditions soon enough :)

Comment: 'only 6-8 years' *only*?

Comment: A little late, but gefeliciteerd, Glorfindel! You definitely seem to have your feet in the clay here.

Comment: We have seen you on many child metas as well :)

Answer (score 39):

This isn't a surprise to me.

Glorfindel is an absolute asset to MSE - Whether it's through the well-reasoned answers he's made to technical questions about the site, or helpful bug reports for new features, Glorfindel's always made good use of his knowledge of the site's innerworkings to better this site and its day-to-day operation. His track record truly does speak for itself.

Congratulations, Glorfindel. I know you'll serve the site well!

Comment: I couldn't have put it better myself!

Answer (score 31):

Can you enlighten us what your stance is on these important topics:

- Stroopwafels
- Elfstedentocht
- Tulpen
- Molens
- Dijken
- 5-3-2

Others like to know

- Bollenstreek
- Bami Ballen
- Zoute drop
- Vla

Please answer carefully. Your responses might haunt you forever ...

Congrats! And great to see my fellow moderator from Stack Apps in this important role.

Comment: *"Your responses might hunt you forever"* - That is so much more terrifying than being haunted by them

Comment: Hey, I have an L on my English

Comment: But *especially* the stroopwafels.

Comment: Do you let the Stroopwafel sit on top of the mug to melt the filling? Inquiring minds want to know.

Comment: @Rosie no... That's just a poor substitute for the warmth of a freshly baked stroopwafel ;)

Comment: What about Bami Ballen? Or Zoute drop?! Those are _obviously_ missing from this list, almost as obvious as Glorfindel is a fit for MSE moderator!

Comment: And how about Vla?

Comment: @Rosie: you would never ask that if you had the chance to visit the [stroopwafel vendor](https://youtu.be/-x7gbt0MGxQ) at the local market.

Comment: @MartijnPieters we're not all so privileged as to have that. There was a market vendor at a Sunday farmers' market here in Austin but that's the closest thing I have seen. :( and they seem to have closed.

Comment: What about *Bollenstreek*? Some Danes have been known to giggle (I am a firsthand witness ([ESTEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Space_Research_and_Technology_Centre), 1992))...

Comment: Dankjewel! On the topic of Dutch food: I tend to prefer healthy stuff; late Spring / early Summer that means asparagus and strawberries. Of course, I will gladly enjoy a stroopwafel, especially when loading carbs for a marathon. But I usually eat a pack of *krentenbollen* the day before.

Comment: I enjoy ice skating a lot, well, as long as it's on non-artificial ice. As you know, that has been in short supply the last years, until last February. I was extremely excited, up to the point where I tried to jump over a crack but fell down and had a concussion ... I'm not sure if I'd be up to an Elfstedentocht; I'd definitely have to work on my technique. I hope my nine year old nephew can teach me ...

Comment: We have 17 million managers of the national soccer team, but I'm not one of them. (Just like I'm probably the only fan of Who is the Mole who doesn't theorize about who the Mole *is*.) I do like watching soccer games with lots of friends dressed in orange, but it's simply not possible right now. I'd say 5-3-2 is fine if it's [the number of goals we score during the group phase matches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_B).

Comment: About Dutch landscapes: I have the privilege to live in a village next to the Veluwe, the largest predominantly natural area in the Netherlands. That means no levees/dikes, and little tulips or other bulbs. We do have one old windmill in the village though, and I like it. What I admire most about our country and its citizens is flexibility, the ability to adapt ourselves to whatever is demanded from us (or don't and fail miserably).

Comment: That's precisely the same thing for which I most admire the Dutch, @Glorfindel. The history of what the Netherlands and its people have managed to do with so little is (or *should be*) a source of inspiration to us all. When you've literally been winning the fight against the flooding of your entire country for centuries, well, that means the rest of us can at least have hope as the planet continues to warm and the ocean levels continue to rise. (Oh, what were we talking about again? You're moderating something on the Internet?)

Answer (score 16):

Glory for Glorfindel!

But forget about MSE moderation team... when are you going to be hired as CM?! :)

Comment: in 6 to 8 weeks most likely :)

Answer (score 13):

Congratulations Glorfindel, on your sixth diamond and the 2nd one earned within 2 weeks (Stack Apps, then MSE)!  Your knowledge of the site, many userscripts, and knowledge of userscripts have always helped me in particular here, and I'm glad to see you with an MSE jewel.

A burning question, though:  Will your first act as an MSE moderator be to rename [waffles](/questions/tagged/waffles) to [stroopwafels](/questions/tagged/stroopwafels)?

Comment: Thanks! I think that action is reversible, so I might keep it in mind for April's fools :) Anyway, I'd have to check with the other Dutch moderator (Tinkeringbell) first...

Comment: @Glorfindel good point, we've got our hopes up! ;)

Answer (score 9):

Congratulations Glorfindel!

For appointed moderator on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) and [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/users?tab=moderators) sites.

Well deserved.

Answer (score 4):

Congrats, Glorfindel!

I'm a little surprised it's taken so long, honestly. I always see you around here, and your contributions have been invaluable.

It's definitely well-deserved, and I know you'll do great! :)