# Please add the link of post related to appointment of moderator in https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators

Tags: feature-request, meta, moderators, users-page

In `users?tab=moderators` page of non-MSE sites, there are links to respective election page for each moderator (like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBDmh.png)).

But, in MSE, just the appointment date is mentioned:

[image]

Please add the link of post related to appointment of each moderator in the page.

- For [Glorfindel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/glorfindel): [Please welcome Glorfindel to the MSE moderation team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/366532)
- For [Journeyman Geek](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/135565/journeyman-geek) and [Tinkeringbell](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/369802/tinkeringbell): [Please Join Us in Welcoming Our New Meta Stack Exchange Moderators!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318630)
- For [ChrisF](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/59303/chrisf), I am not sure because of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382601)...

Comment: Is there a particular piece of information in these appointment posts you're looking for? Is this just out of general interest or something else?

Comment: @BSMP General interest and also for consistency

Answer (score 6):

There are appointed moderators on most SE sites, i.e. at least 150 probably more.

Adding link to each requires a staff member to go and look for the relevant meta post.

This means wasting long hours on something that I don't think is really important.

Bottom line: better have the staff spend their time on more productive things. :)

In case you mean doing it only here on MSE then it would break consistency, so also not a good idea.

Comment: Do beta sites have appointed moderators? or else some other sites? Please provide examples if possible.

Comment: @RandomPerson Prior to 2018, beta sites' moderators used to be appointed rather than elected. There are several such sites that are either still in beta or have launched but not had their first full election yet, meaning there are many dozens of appointed moderators across the network.

Comment: Also, since the oldest record is shown, moderators who were originally appointed under the old process and later went on to win a full election on the site after it launched will still show their prior appointment date (by design, so their past work isn't downplayed).

Comment: @RandomPerson just look in elections page of almost each SE site, you'll see "appointed" without link in most of them.