# What is the difference between meta and meta stack?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, meta

I've been participating in stack overflow for a while and for some reason just realized today that there are (at least) *two* meta sites for stack overflow:

> https://meta.stackexchange.com/
>
> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/

This might be a dumb question, but what is the difference between these two and what belongs on the stack site versus the exchange site?

Comment: Until recently you're right, it was the same site. Now http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ is just the meta site for Stack Overflow, no different than any other meta site on the Stack Exchange network. The split is described here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212631/stack-overflow-is-getting-a-place-of-its-own.