# Hyperlink to the old meta site available on user's profile

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, per-site-meta

When looking at my friends Stack Overflow profile I noticed the meta user link (as highlighted in red):

[image: screen shot for Stack Overflow]

When I click it, it brings up the old meta website with an incorrect reputation for that user and badge count:

[image: Screen shot for Meta Stack Overflow]

Comment: 'old' meta site? It is newer than MSE..

Comment: See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212631/stack-overflow-is-getting-a-place-of-its-own).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). "Meta User" is the link to the user's profile on Meta Stack Overflow (as you see). There's an analog link there: "Main User", which links back to the Stack Overflow profile. That's how all (other) sites work vis-a-vis "Meta User"/"Main User".

Meta Stack Exchange is a completely different site/profile.

You might have a look at some of the information about the [MSO/MSE split](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mso-mse-split).

Answer (score 3):

Not a bug - MSO is now a normal child meta, and inherits reputation from SO. :)