# Personalization of Careers advertisements

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-deferred, jobs, advertising

I get a lot of Careers ads which don't really suit my expected position. E.g. I see myself more in the [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) world than in [java](/questions/tagged/java). Some may say the language does not matter, but my personal feeling is that all my class library knowledge and debugging know-how is in the Microsoft world.

Now, how to get rid of the Java Careers ads?

Note that I don't have [java](/questions/tagged/java) under my favorite tags. But I also don't have it on my ignore list, since I can (sometimes) answer Java questions.

**Suggestion**: I'd like to upvote or downvote ads as I see them and not see the downvoted ones again. If I recall correctly, that would be similar to [Open source ads](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260377/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2h-2014).

Drawback of this solution: it seems the number of ads is quite limited. I see the same ads again and again. It might happen that Careers once runs out of ads to be displayed for me.

**Alternative** approach: let me somewhere (presumably on the Careers website) specify which tags I'd like to exclude.

Drawback of this solution: I can't do it on Stack Overflow itself. If I need to switch to Careers first, that's probably too much effort.

Comment: Possibly worth a look at your [prediction data](http://stackoverflow.com/users/prediction-data) to see if the system has figured you out correctly or not? At least for entertainment value?

Comment: @StevenV: Insightful. It finds "backend web developer" for me. I'd define myself as "Other Desktop developer" in the available choices. That could be one of the reasons. Or perhaps I should start looking for different jobs :-)

Comment: Why is this on Meta SE now? Careers is listed *under* Stack Overflow, isn't it? At least in the drop down menu at the top of the page.

Comment: @ThomasW. It's a judgment call, but I migrated it because this is not specific to Stack Overflow. For one, we run job ads on Server Fault as well, and advertising-related feature requests are more of a network-wide thing. Part of the rationale for the MSE/MSO split was to be able to keep MSO a little more focused on the SO community, and a little less on miscellaneous product requests like this. Although this isn't really a Careers request, Careers requests also belong on MSE. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212631/stack-overflow-is-getting-a-place-of-its-own

Comment: *Now, how to get rid of the Java Careers ads?* OP seems like a pretty cool guy

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow has [discontinued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293) Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story on March 31, 2022.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **Update (March 12, 2015)**: We decided that filtering based on Stack Overflow ignored tags was a bad idea, because, for example, you may not want to answer questions in [sql](/questions/tagged/sql), but aren't necessarily opposed to accepting a job which deals with SQL. So, instead, we are now respecting your disliked tags on Careers. So, if you have a Careers CV (which is linked to your Stack Exchange account), then you should never see any jobs which are tagged with one of your disliked tags.
>
> This is not a perfect solution. We still want better ways for you to control your advertising preferences, even if you don't have a Careers account. This wasn't a calculated ploy to try to get more people to sign up for Careers; it was simply the easiest way to implement it quickly. This is a first small step in the right direction, and hopefully some users will find it useful.

This is absolutely something we want to do. Simply respecting your ignored tags list on Stack Overflow may be the starting point for this sort of functionality. I understand that may not be useful in your specific case, but it may be a win for other users, and is a quicker way to get going than the suggestions you describe.

As AstroCB wrote, we recently rolled out more intelligent targeting, but it's just a small first step, and there's still a lot of randomness involved, so seeing ads which don't even match what we think we know about you is still pretty likely to happen. Geography is the biggest influence on the job ads you see, so if you're seeing a lot of duplicates, it's likely because there aren't that many jobs in your area.

Long term we want to give you much more control over the ads you see. Voting may be part of that. You bring up the scenario of what if I down vote everything, and Careers has nothing left to show me? We actually think that's okay. If we don't have anything relevant to show you, then why are we showing you anything? One of the future options will very likely be an option to completely disable job ads for a certain period of time (~6 months maybe). If you're not even remotely interested in considering switching jobs in the near future, then there's very little benefit in us showing you job ads.

None of this is a promise, just an indication of some of the ideas we've been kicking around. Ads are going through major changes behind the scenes, and we have a lot of work to do before we can even begin to design or build these more-ideal solutions. I'm marking your request as [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred). We'd love to get to it, but I can't even begin to give you a timeline.

---

<sub>Shameless self plug: if anyone reading this answer is a smart developer with a passion for making ads on Stack Overflow better, we are currently [hiring for the Ad Server team.](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/62162/ad-server-technology-developer-stack-exchange)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

How about some good news bad news.

Good news:  We're working on this!  Not exactly as you stated, but we're getting smarter about how we target ads.  See our [latest blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/targeted-jobs-for-stack-overflow/) for updates on our efforts to better target jobs recently.

This is just the start though.  We're tweaking our current algorithms to be smarter about identifying what types of jobs you'd be interested in, and hopefully soon(ish) will be incorporating data from Careers (job searches, Careers Profile data etc...) to enhance this.  This is closer to your alternative suggestion.

Bad news:  The voting on ads is not on our roadmap right now.  It may get there in the future, but we're not there yet.  And, this stuff takes a lot of time to test and get right.

Answer (score 1):

This is already in place. Targeted ads [are rolling out slowly](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/targeted-jobs-for-stack-overflow/), and they will attempt to show you ads relevant to not only your location, but your frequented tags:

> Until today, the job ads that we show on Stack Overflow were pretty stupid: they targeted solely based on location, and ignored all the other information about what you’re looking for and what kind of job it is. They didn’t even care about whether the job was in a technology that you were interested in. So today* we’re launching the first step in showing you jobs that we think are an actual match for you.
>
> <sub>*If you just ran to a question to see how targeted the jobs were and left disappointed, don’t worry. This feature is just launching today and most employers haven’t had a chance to target their jobs yet. You’ll see the difference over the coming months.</sub>

Note that there is no way to vote on these ads (and if you're asking for that, I could understand why, but I'm not sure it's feasible) because they are generated by Stack Overflow Careers and its partners. If you're looking for something even more personalized, I'd change your request to reflect that.