# Will Meta Stack Exchange keep its name or will it be named Meta Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, meta

Recently it was announced that Stack Exchange will rename itself to Stack Overflow. I am wondering, will Meta Stack Exchange keep its name or will it be named Meta Stack Overflow?

Meta Stack Overflow is more logical because it is about all Stack Overflow sites but
if it will be renamed to Meta Stack Overflow, how to prevent confusion between this Meta and Stack Overflow, the site for programming questions, Meta?

Comment: They are not "all Stack Overflow sites", they are "all Stack Exchange sites".

Comment: related: [Stack Overflow is getting a place of its own](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212631/165773)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The network of sites is still Stack Exchange.

[Source](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/09/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/?cb=1)

> Well, as of today, people like me will start saying we "work for Stack Overflow.” I guess we’ll need new business cards, too? Hopefully someone’s on that already. But I digress. In the weeks ahead, we’ll change the name of things like the blog, podcast, and any other places where “Stack Exchange” was referring to the company, as opposed to the network of Q&A sites. **Our Q&A sites will still be collectively known as the Stack Exchange Network.**

Comment: I see. I should've read the entire blog, not just skimmed through it.

Comment: @wythagoras full transparency: I didn't remember that, but just searched the blog for "Stack Exchange" until I found the relevant section  ;)