# How can I see example of community wiki?

Tags: support, community-wiki

So I just got ability to edit community wiki but I have no idea what that is.
Also answers do not tell me what is it, where is it, what is looks like?

Yes I've read answers like this:
[What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

But it gives no examples of what the things looks like.

Comment: `Also answers do not tell me what is it, where is it, what is looks like?` The post you referenced tells you *all* of those things.

Comment: I suggest that says somewhere in the post. "THIS IS A COMMUNITY WIKI POST". Because this hint was too subtle for me, so it's probably too subtle for a percentage of users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question you linked, and all its answers, are community wiki. Notice how, in the bottom-right where the author's usercard would normally be, it says "community wiki." Below that, you'll find information like the number of revisions.

This is a usercard from a normal Super User post by me:

[image: normal]

And this is one from a wiki post mostly written by me:

[image: community wiki]

Note that the links to the user for some community wiki posts here on MSE might not go to the user page, likely because of [the MSO/MSE split](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212631/295684).

Answer (score 2):

As already said by Ben, the post you linked is a community wiki.

If you look for more examples, you can use the search option `wiki:yes`. It will give you [all community wiki questions and answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=wiki%3Ayes).

I have also [edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/11741/52) the community wiki you referenced to include the identification method.