# How do redirects from Meta Stack Overflow to here work?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, meta, redirection, mso-mse-split

One of the comments in the [AutoReviewComments](https://stackapps.com/q/2116/34061) userscript contains a link to Meta Stack Overflow: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259 which *automatically redirects* to a [Meta Stack Exchange answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259). With some research, I found that this is part of the [Meta split](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212631/295232):

> 3. Establish redirects from MSO to MSE for lower post IDs

However, I couldn't find how this works exactly. Is it just that post IDs under a certain number are automatically redirected? If so, what is that number (perhaps [250000](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/701814))? The redirection seems to be active only for Meta Stack Overflow, not for other meta sites. Under circumstances, it can also redirect to other sites, e.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/200000.

While this is a great playground (just plugging in numbers and seeing where you end up) I'd also appreciate an answer by a Stack Overflow employee with the 'functional specifications' of this feature.

Also, the redirect isn't working properly in the iOS app (presumably because of the way the API works); I get the familiar 'question not found' screen inviting me to open the page in Safari (where it does work).

Comment: The exception you found which redirects to mathoverflow meta isn't really an exception, it was manually migrated: https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/200000/revisions. (so not relevant)

Comment: True, but it's still interesting, as the migration history link of that question is broken.

Comment: Only because the redirection works for specific URL pattern.